# Way to Treat Python single vals and lists of vals identically?

Tags: python, list

I'm running into this problem often:  I'm creating a function that needs to perform a series of operations on a value, whether that value be a single value or a list of values.

Is there an elegant way to do this:

```
def convert_val(val):
   do a series of things to each value, whether list or single val
   return answer or list of answers
```

rather than what I've been doing?:

```
def convert_val(val):
    if isinstance(val, list):
       ... do a series of things to each list item,
       return a list of answers
    else:
       ... do the same series, just on a single value
       return a single answer
```

One solution would be to create a sub_convert() that would do the series of actions, and then just call it once or iteratively, depending on the type passed in to convert().

Another would be to create a single convert() that would accept the arguments (value, sub_convert()).

Other suggestions that would be more compact, elegant and preferably all in one function?

(I've done several searches here to see if my issue has already been addressed.  My appologies if it has.)

Thanks,
JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the function makes sense for a single value, as well as for a list, then logically the function's result for a certain list item will not depend on the other items in the list.

For example, `a` and `b` should end up identical:

```
items = [1, 2]
a = convert_val(items)
b = map(convert_val, items)
```

This example already hints at the solution: the *caller* knows whether a list or a single value is passed in. When passing a single value, the function can be used as-is. When passing a list, a `map` invocation is easily added, and makes it clearer what's happening on the side of the caller.

Hence, the function you describe should not exist in the first place!

Comment: The map() call is also a good idea I hadn't considered.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need to fix your design to make all uses of the function actually correct.

Ralph Waldo Emerson.  "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds, adored by little statesmen and philosophers and divines."

We're not talking about a foolish consistency.  You have what might be a design problem based on inconsistent use of this function.

Option 1.  Don't call `convert_val( x )` where `x` is a non-list.  Do this.  `convert_val( [x] )`.   Don't fix your function, fix all the places that use your function.  Consistency helps reduce bugs.

Option 2.  Change the design of `convert_val` to use multiple positional arguments.  This doesn't generalize well.

```
def convert_val( *args ):
    whatever it's supposed to do to the arguments.
```

Then fix all the places you provide a list to be `convert_val( *someList )`.  That's okay, and may be closer to your intent.

Note.

You can find your design errors using the `warnings` module.

```
def convert_val( arg ):
    if isinstance( arg, collections.Sequence ):
        return convert_val_list( arg )
    else:
        warnings.warn( "Fix this" )
        return convert_val_list( [arg] )[0]

def convert_val_list( arg ):
    assert isinstance( arg, collections.Sequence )
    the original processing
```

Once you've fixed all the design problems, you can then do this

```
convert_val = convert_val_list
```

And delete the original function.

Comment: Both good options I hadn't thought of.  Thank you.  Thanks also for the tip on the warnings module.

Comment: The above is fine when you know what you're passing in. In my case, I used Selenium to fetch a value and it gives me different results depending on which browser I am running, i.e. one gives me a String the other gives me a list with one String.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party here and I'm not sure if this is what OP wants.

I much prefer to keep the implementation details hidden inside the function. The caller shouldn't care about what happens inside.

```
def convert_val(val):
    values = []
    values.extend(val)
    for value in values:
        # do things to each list item,
    return a list of answers
```

This would make the `convert_val` put `val` into the `values` list (if not a list) or all values of `val` into the `values` list.

In addition should predictably get a list back (since you'd be using the same logic).

In the end:

```
assert convert_val([1]) == convert_val(1)
```